# Spritesheet Animation in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sprite-sheet

This is a tutorial from MSDN that I am using, the problem is I can't make any progress because of not knowing what replaces the elipsis as everything I have tried comes back with an error.

```
private AnimatedTexture SpriteTexture;
private const float Rotation = 0;
private const float Scale = 2.0f;
private const float Depth = 0.5f;
public Game1()
{
    ... //this is where I am stuck
    SpriteTexture = new AnimatedTexture(Vector2.Zero, Rotation, Scale, Depth);

    // Set device frame rate to 30 fps.
    TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / 30.0);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?  You say everything was going okay...presumably now it's not, but you don't say what the issue is.

Comment: My main issue is not knowing what is meant to go in place of the elipsis ("...") so I can't continue until I know is meant to be there.

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial?  There is not enough information here to help you.

Comment: The tutorial isn't compatable with my version of visual studio

Answer (score 0):

You should [download the .zip with source code](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=198823) that goes with [the tutorial I believe you're trying to follow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb203866.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  For one thing, `AnimatedTexture` is a custom class that's not defined.  Open `AnimatedSprite.sln` to get what you need from Microsoft's sample code.

In the zip is the rest of the `Game1` class, the constructor you're referencing being:

```
    private AnimatedTexture SpriteTexture;
    private const float Rotation = 0;
    private const float Scale = 2.0f;
    private const float Depth = 0.5f;
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        SpriteTexture = new AnimatedTexture(Vector2.Zero,
            Rotation, Scale, Depth);
#if ZUNE
        // Frame rate is 30 fps by default for Zune.
        TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / 30.0);
#endif
    }
```